# Tracking Download for enterprise iPhone/iPad application through itms-services

Tags: iphone, enterprise

I am using itms-services to download enterprise iPhone/iPad application. We want to track who has downloaded what application when the user clicks Download button.

As prompt to Cancel/ Download is coming from itms-services not by our application, we are finding difficulties to track that download click event. Can anybody give any way out to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way to intercept the Cancel/Download from this IOS prompt. The only way to ensure that you know that a download has occurred would be to have the file server detect the download of the entire file. Even then, it is possible that a user could "cancel" the download near the end, or if the file was built incorrectly (i.e., profile is invalid) that the load to springboard is incomplete.

If you use a system like EASE (Enterprise App Services Environment) [http://www.apperian.com/ease], it provides this type of information based on the completion of file downloading and has reporting. EASE is free to developers using ad-hoc deployment so if you are trying to distribute apps this might be an option for you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your web access log of .ipa?  It'll give you rough idea of how many downloads.

Answer (score 0):

You could write JavaScript code that:

1. contacts google's tracking services, and then
2. changes the window.location to your iTMS-services link.

Comment: What I forgot to mention is to sign up for google's tracking service first. I can't remember what it's called at the moment, sorry about that. Google will give a URL/js that allows you to add 1 to its tracking syste,.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, here is my working solution.  This logs the enterprise download click to google analytics.

```
<!-- Users click on this install link -->
<a href="#" onclick="trackOutboundLink('{{ download_url }}'); return false;">Install App</a>

<script>
    var trackOutboundLink = function (url) {
        ga('send', 'event', 'Download Page', 'User Clicked Install', url, {'hitCallback': function () {
            window.location.href = url;
        }
        });
    };
 </script>
```